# Why some XP terminals don't automatically Start SQL2005 service

Tags: windows-xp, sql, windows-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why some XP installs don’t automatically Start SQL2005 Service (Instance)](https://serverfault.com/questions/16431/why-some-xp-installs-dont-automatically-start-sql2005-service-instance)

I have a number couple of XP machines that have a SQL 2005 Instance running on them, and they are set to automatic in Service Control Manager.

If you reboot one of these machines, the SQL Instance doesn't start. Nothing makes it into the event log that something was wrong.

I was wondering if anyone had any clues about what might be going wrong with these?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server Logs?

Comment: This is NPR - it's an application admin issue. So you'll probably have better luck over on serverfault (or another site until you get to 100 rep). Here's a start. + 1. Now you just need to find another 9 nice guys like me :-)

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/16431/why-some-xp-installs-dont-automatically-start-sql2005-service-instance (this one was asked first on Stack Overflow, then migrated).

Answer (score 0):

What about the SQL Server logs (Not LDFs)?

Can you start the services start later?

Is there a dependency on another servers?

Answer (score 0):

1. dependency
2. permission